# How to control NServiceBus queue name when hosted on Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, nservicebus, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

For some reason the queue hosted on windows azure is not respecting the `.DefineEndpointName()` configuration.

The queue name on Azure Bus is always named after the worker role that's hosting it. While this is fine, in general, I'd feel a lot better if there was an option to manually override the convention.

How can I define my own queue name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration setting that can be used to control the queue name:

You can add it to your service configuration files like this,

<Setting name="AzureQueueConfig.QueueName" value="yourqueue" />

Or add it in app.config like this:

<AzureQueueConfig QueueName="yourqueue" />

PS: Define endpoint name should work as well, can you reproduce the issue in a small sample and file it as an issue on https://github.com/nservicebus/nservicebus

Thanks,
Yves

Comment: Yves you're right if I speced it in the QueueName, it works fine, but it's not looking at the endpoint namespace at all. Thanks for the tip! I'll see if I can upload it as an issue.